# Where to place PHP code for a node if not in the node body block itself?

Tags: 7, nodes

Up until now, I have found it most convenient and easy to place PHP code into my node by placing it in the node body and enabling the PHP filter. However, I have been informed that this is incorrect and unsafe.

Furthermore, I also know that it would be incorrect to place PHP code in node.tpl.php.

Could someone please tell me where the correct place to place PHP code for a node would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of two places, [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) or [`hook_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). They can both be used in a module file, but only the latter will work in your theme's template.php file.

`hook_node_view()` example:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_node_type') {
    $args = array(':nid' => $node->nid);
    $my_value = db_query('SELECT my_field FROM {my_table} WHERE nid = :nid', $args)->fetchField();

    $node->content['my_value'] = array(
      '#markup' => 'My value is: ' . $my_value, 
      '#weight' => 10 // Controls the display order of this piece of content
    );
  }
}
```

`hook_preprocess_node()` example:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['content']['my_additional_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $additional_field, 
    '#weight' => 10, 
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks. But if for example I wish Node A to display some data from the database, in which file should I put that code?

Comment: Are you familiar with writing custom modules? Or would you rather do this in your theme?

Comment: I am very familiar with writing custom modules. I just can't (conceptually) complete the link between how my module will affect the display of a node body content. (ie. If I have your first hook_node_view in my custom module, would I have to create another file to actually put the PHP code that would grab the database content?)

Comment: Gotcha. In your `node.tpl.php` file you'll probably have the line `print render($content);`, which prints out all of the node content. In the preprocess/node_view function you can query the database and add to the `$node->content` or `$vars['content']` render array. I'll update the first method in the answer with an example

Comment: I got it working. But I am having trouble returning a list of values from the query. I currently have $query = db_query('SELECT OFFICE_ID FROM OFFICE LIMIT 0, 10')->fetchField();, however this only returns me the first field. I have tried 'fetchObject' and 'fetchCol' but both only a string 'Array', which gets printed out as in your code. Do you know how I can display the entire list that is returned by the query?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the values and build up the string, something like: `$results = db_query('SELECT my_field FROM {my_table} WHERE nid = :nid', $args); $string = ''; foreach ($results as $result) { $string .= $result->OFFICE_ID . '<br />'; } $node->content['my_value'] = array('#markup' => $string);`